# How can I in a pivot filter detail to show new accounts in current month with sales where all other months show no sales?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which is huge with raw data has more than 800,000 lines.  I have customers in the row labels and month or year in the column labels.

Each month this pivot tablr grows adding on the previous month of sales data reporting, e.g. I just finished compiling and reporting February sales, so I have all of 2012, 2013 and now January and February of 2014.

From this pivot table, I need to pull out any account in the *current month* having sales where *all other months* have none.  I'm struggling on how to achieve this in the pivot table. So I'm thinking I need to find a formula that yields a Y/N for new or not in a column of the raw data.

Can anyone help or advise how this can be accomplished? I'm more than willing to also send a sample of data so you can see how my pivot is laid out and how the raw data looks as well.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, a "helper" column is needed.  Assuming your data looks something like this:
[image]

I added column D, which I called "New Customer?" containing this formula in D2 and filled down:
`=IF(SUMIFS($C$2:$C$8,$A$2:$A$8,A2,$B$2:$B$8,"<"&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1))=0,"Y","N")`

This figures out the total prior month sales for the unique customer name/number, and if it is ZERO, then sets this flag to "Y"/yes.

From here, we can put this as a report filter in our pivot, to get customers without prior month sales only:
[image]